# Primeng contextmenu with turbotable : how to remove row selection when closing the context menu

Tags: angular, contextmenu, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I'm using the `contextmenu` with `turbotable` of `primeng` (version 6.1.0).

Based on the demo on the website, when you right click on a row, the context menu appears and the row is selected but when you click outside of the context menu, the menu disappears but the row is still selected. What I want is that the row is deselected when the context menu is hidden.

See https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/contextmenu

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 6):

Add `contextMenuSelectionMode="joint"` to your p-table object.

Like so:

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedCar" [contextMenu]="cm" contextMenuSelectionMode="joint">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData" [pContextMenuRow]="rowData">
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Per https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5558#issuecomment-404088622